# Cocos2d-x crash with error fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) on some device android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm a newest in cocos2d-x. In my game I want to create sprite in each time and control sprites of position to find out game over. My game run well on ios but crash on some android device with error fatal signal 11 (sigsegv). I debug by use ndk_stack and it shows that crash on timerUpdate() function. Can someone shows me where my error, thanks. This is my code.

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{   
    spriteArr = CCArray::create();  
    spriteArr->retain();
}

void HelloWorld::onRestartGame(CCObject* pSender)
{
    CCLog("Restart game");
    _counter = 0;
_scoreLabel->setString(CCString::createWithFormat("%d", _counter)->getCString());

    CCObject* obj;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(spriteArr, obj) {
        MySprite *sprite = (MySprite *)obj;
        this->removeChild(sprite, true);
    }
        spriteArr->removeAllObjects();
        this->addNewSprite();
        this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::gameLogic), 0.1f );
}


void HelloWorld::gameLogic(float dt)
{
    this->timerUpdate();
}

void HelloWorld::addNewSprite()
{
    MySprite *ant = (MySprite *)MySprite::create();
    sprite->addSpriteTo(this);  //Add sprite to scence
    spriteArr->addObject(sprite);
}

void HelloWorld::timerUpdate()
{
     CCObject* obj;
     CCARRAY_FOREACH(spriteArr, obj) {
     MySprite *sprite = (MySprite *)obj;

    int _x = sprite->x + moving_distance*cos(sprite->angle * M_PI/180);
    int _y = sprite->y + moving_distance*sin(sprite->angle * M_PI/180);

    if ((_x <= game_over_left) ||
        (_y <= game_over_bottom) ||
        (_x >= game_over_right) ||
        (_y > game_over_top)) {
        // Game over
        sprite->stopAnimation();
        this->unscheduleAllSelectors();
        // Display game over
        this->onGameOver() ;
        return;
    } else {
        sprite->updatePosition(_x, _y, sprite->angle);
        sprite->setPosition(CCPoint(_x, _y));
    }            
}
this->stopAntatPoint(_fingerPoint);

_counter++;
if (_counter%20 == 0) {
    // Add new sprite
    this->addNewSprite();
}

    _scoreLabel->setString(CCString::createWithFormat("%d", _counter/20 + 1)->getCString());
}
```

Comment: I think in timerUpdate() function I modify apriteArr in multi thread, so some android devices can't control pointer and heap memory corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried debug build? [ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1](https://gitorious.org/mingw-android-ndk/mingw-android-ndk/source/07c5eb78ec041d66b0ce5f9668f2e5b78552826d:docs/NDK-BUILD.TXT) with [this Application.mk](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/templates/cpp-template-default/proj.android/jni/Application.mk). You'll get more detailed stack trace.

Comment: try using ndk-stack with adb to find out stacktrace hierarchy. Check http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-use-ndk-stack-tool-to-debug-cocos2d-x-android-project/11701/2